# making an instance of a class only in particular iterations of a for loop

Tags: c#, for-loop, logic, instance

The code below doesn't seem to work. The goal of the function is to divide a bitmap (LockBitmap) into blocks of 8 by 8 pixels and store them in an array.

I wrote a class MotionBlock that contains the X and Y component of the block and a 8x8 integer containing the values of the bitmap.

The function loops through the width and height property of lbmp. everytime i mod 8 is 0 and j mod 8 is 0, a new instance of motionBlock should be made, and the X and Y property should be assigned. for other iterations, a value should be assigned to int array of grayvalues.

After assigning the value of the last pixel, the MotionBlock should be copied to the array, and a new MotionBlock should be made in the next iteration (which should be again twice 0 mod 8), starting the proces all over again till the end of the loops.

**Problem:** the array seems to be empty. In the code below i try to make an instance of MotionBlock outside the for-loop, use it in the for-loop, and after every 8x8 pixels writing it to the array, and just overwriting the motionblock after in the iterations there after.

I think that's not the right way to do it, but when i make an instance of motionBlock in a if-statement i can't use it outside of the if-statement, so i'm stuck finding a way to make an instance, use it for a few iterations, writing it to an array, and then proceeding with a new instance.

```
public static MotionBlock[] getImageBlocks(LockBitmap lbmp)
{
    int x = lbmp.Width / 8;
    int y = lbmp.Height / 8;
    int surface = x * y;

    MotionBlock[] blocks = new MotionBlock[surface];
    MotionBlock block = new MotionBlock();

    int teller = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < lbmp.Width; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < lbmp.Height; j++)
        {
            if (i % 8 == 0 && j % 8 == 0)
            {
                block.X = i;
                block.Y = j;
            }

            int r = i % 8;
            int k = j % 8;

            block.GrayValues[r, k] = lbmp.GetPixel(i, j).R;
            Console.WriteLine(block.grayValues[r, k]);

            if (i % 8 == 7 && i % 8 == 7)
            {
                blocks[teller] = block;
            }

            teller++;
        }

        teller++;
    }

    return blocks;
}
```

Comment: You need to tell us how it is not working?  What do you expect and what are you actually getting?

Comment: @ChrisDunaway alright will edit

Comment: I don't think you want the second `teller++`

Comment: What do `block.X` and `block.Y` properties represent? Taking the first block as an example should `(block.X, block.Y)` equal `(0, 0)` or `(7, 7)`

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to declare a new block when `x` and `y` are `0`, otherwise you're constantly updating the same `block`. Also, you don't need to increment your index twice at the end of the `Height` loop. Finally, for readability, it might be helpful to use more descriptive variable names than `i`, `j`, `r`, and `k`.

Here is the modified code (the main change is the addition of `block = new MotionBlock` when `blockX` and `blockY` are `0`):

```
public static MotionBlock[] getImageBlocks(LockBitmap lockBitmap)
{
    int surface = (lockBitmap.Width / 8) * (lockBitmap.Height / 8);

    MotionBlock[] blocks = new MotionBlock[surface];
    MotionBlock block = new MotionBlock();

    int blockIndex = 0;

    for (int imageX = 0; imageX < lockBitmap.Width; imageX++)
    {
        for (int imageY = 0; imageY < lockBitmap.Height; imageY++)
        {
            // Get the block-level X and Y coordinates
            int blockX = imageX % 8;
            int blockY = imageY % 8;

            // If we are at the start of a new block, create it
            if (blockX == 0 && blockY == 0)
            {
                block = new MotionBlock {X = imageX, Y = imageY};
            }

            // Set the gray values of the current block and output to console
            block.GrayValues[blockX, blockY] = lockBitmap.GetPixel(imageX, imageY).R;
            Console.WriteLine(block.grayValues[blockX, blockY]);

            // If we are at the end of a block, save it to our array
            if (blockX == 7 && blockY == 7)
            {
                blocks[blockIndex] = block;
            }

            // Increment our block array index
            blockIndex++;
        }
    }

    return blocks;
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't work either, that's exactly the problem, you can't acces block outside the if statement because you instanciated it in the if-statement.

Comment: Yes you can. The declaration is outside the `for` loop, therefore it has scope inside the for loop and inside all `if` statements within that (notice that I'm not *creating* a *new* variable, I'm just *reassigning* the *existing* one)...

Comment: In fact, it could be declared inside the second for loop and the code would still work just fine. Are you getting an exception? If so, can you post it (and the line number)?

Comment: Here's a link to the error i'm getting:
[link](http://s30.postimg.org/m57183cmp/mot.png)

Comment: Ah, ok. It's because I didn't assign it originally (logically I know it will be assigned, but apparently the compiler doesn't see that). If you add an assignment at declaration, that should fix it: `MotionBlock block = new MotionBlock();` I'll update the sample, too.

Comment: still don't get any output though

Comment: Step through it with the debugger...the code looks correct, so there must be some other issue.

Answer (score -2):

I believe all you are looking for here is a continue statement.

From what I understand you simply want to ignore a given iteration of the loop when the condition

> "i mod 8 is 0 and j mod 8 is 0"

is not satisfied.Therefore I would suggest adding a continue at the end of this if block

```
if (i % 8 == 0 && j % 8 == 0)
    {
        block.X = i;
        block.Y = j;
    }
else
    continue;
```

Comment: No i don't want to ignore it, I want to do something else. Let me try to explain it a little:

Comment: No i don't want to ignore it, I want to do something else. Let me try to explain it a little:
'
if (i % 8 == 0 && j % 8 == 0)
{
MotionBlock block = new MotionBlock();
block.X = i;
block.Y = j;
}

int r = i % 8;
int k = j % 8;

int r = i % 8;

block.GrayValues[r, k] = lbmp.GetPixel(i, j).R;

Console.WriteLine(block.grayValues[r, k]);
if (i % 8 == 7 && i % 8 == 7)
{
   blocks[teller] = block;
}


teller++;
'